# how to find text inside a tag using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a paragraph like below

```
<p>The strength of the notion of the cultural biography, in my mind, is that it provides us with a way to escape from these preoccupations <xref>1990</xref>.  The algorithm takes a set of earthly 1989 biographies as input and produces a set of improved resurrection 1915 biographies as output.</p>
```

I need to find untagged year in a `<p>` Tag. I try a code please check below

```
if($xml.find("p").length > 0)
{
    var $element = $xml.find("p").addBack("p");
    $element.each(function()
    {
        if($(this).clone().find('xref').remove().end().text().match(/19+[0-9][0-9]/))
        {
            //*****
        }                           

    });
}
```

But this code return single untagged year, I want complete year list in a paragraph

Comment: less jquery in the world please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var $container=$(this).find("xref").remove().text().match(/\d+/g);


   var num =$(this).find("#value").text().match(/\d+/g).join(",");
    console.log( num);  
         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p id="value">The strength of the notion of the cultural biography, in my mind, is that it provides us with a way to escape from these preoccupations <xref>1990</xref> The algorithm takes a set of earthly 1989 biographies as input and produces a set of improved resurrection 1915  biographies as output.</p>
```

Comment: 'var untagged_19_20 = untagged_19_20.replace(/( 19+[0-9][0-9])/g, '<span class="ref_highlght">$1</span>'); ' how to use replace here

Comment: @Swashi your solution only for the years that start with 19 and it is specific for your text only. while using this code will work for any number. best regards.

Answer (score 0):

using regex for matching all numbers `length of 4` with `leading and trailing spaces`.

try below solution

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     var regexp = /(\s+)\d{1,4}(\s+)/g;
     var txt = $('p').text();
     var match, matches = [];

     while ((match = regexp.exec(txt)) != null) {
       matches.push(parseInt(match[0].replace(/\s/g, '')));
     }

     console.log(matches);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>The strength of the notion of the cultural biography, in my mind, is that it provides us with a way to escape from these preoccupations <xref>1990</xref>.   The algorithm takes a set of earthly 1989 biographies as input and produces a set of improved resurrection 1915  biographies as output.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, But I need to find UNTAGGED Year example Output should be 1989, 1915

Comment: @Swashichanged logic accordingly. test pls

Answer (score 0):

Get the untagged year values

```
var untagged_19_20 = $(this).clone().find('xref').remove().end().text().match(/19+[0-9][0-9]/g);
var untagged_19_20 = untagged_19_20 + ',' + $(this).clone().find('xref').remove().end().text().match(/20+[0-9][0-9]/g);
```